# Excel VBA - Saved Workbook in loop within macro...Workbook fails to open

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So, in retrospect, this may not have been the best way to go about de-bugging my application. But here is a brief overview of what has happened:

1. Created macro to loop through files and extract data from each file and dump into a consolidated workbook
2. Macro was getting hung in really long loop near the end
3. In order to preserve the data after it hung (for the purposes of understanding where/how it was getting hung in the loop), I added a Workbook.Save command at the end of each iteration
4. The loop made it to the final iteration and got hung.
5. I re-opened the workbook and all the data is present, however it is still hung in the loop

My questions:

1. I cannot break (CTRL + Break) the loop, is there any other way to kill current execution?
2. Is it possible that when Excel saves the document after the iteration, it will pick back up at the point of execution within the macro when the book is re-opened?
3. Finally, is there anyway to extract the macro from the seemingly corrupted workbook?

Comment: Two things: 1) Add `DoEvents` to the inside of the loop. 2) you can open the workbook without any code executing by going to the open menu and holding shift while pressing the open button.

Comment: Have you tried a `Stop` command at the end of the loop and stepping through the next data extraction commands? You may want to add a counter to monitor iterations

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk a little bit in the dark here, as you didn't give any code to refer to.

1. If loop doesn't have an end it usually ends with restarting Excel. Breaking option is not really working in that situation.
2. If you had assigned Workbook to the variable you can close it with saving the changes:

   ```
   Dim wb as Workbook
   ...
   wb.Close True
   ```
3. You can copy Sheet with a macro in it to the another Workbook.